# Get Request URL from XHR in network chrome developer

Tags: vba, selenium

I am using selenium VBA and on the page there is a search button that I click on using this line

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//button[@aria-label='search']").Click
```

When clicking on this button and inspecting the Network tab and XHR there is a response. How can I get the request url from xhr object?

Comment: Is the button in a form?  If Yes then presumably you can inspect the parent form; if No then you'd need to somehow find the event handler for the button.

Comment: No, it is not in a form. How can find the event handler?

Comment: You'd need to maybe examine the page to see if you can find some pointers there.  There may not be an easy way though.